# What is the eigenvalue and eigenvector for $T$ on $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that $U$ is a subspace of the space of infinitely differential-able (complex valued) functions of real numbers that is spanned by $f_1=e^t \cos(t)$ and $f_2=e^t \sin(t)$.

What is the eigenvalue and eigenvector for $T$ on $U$? Given:

$T(f)=\frac {df}{dt}$

$T\in \mathcal L \left({U}\right)$

### My attempt

I think i should find the matrix with respect to a basis then I should find the characteristic equation. Not sure how to piece this all together.

Comment: As written, the question makes no sense: you are not saying what $T$ is.

Comment: But you already have the matrix representation of $\;T\;$ restricted to $\;U\;$ and even its characteristic polynomial in my answer to your last question, so why don't you use this?

Comment: @Joanpemo can I just use that matrix and do |M(T) - $\lambda I$| = 0?

Comment: @combostudent Of course ! After all you want to work out eigenvalues, eigenvectors and etc. for $\;T|_U\;$ , which is an operator in a $\;2-$ dimensional space.

Comment: seems like $\lambda$ does not have any real values (if i am doing it right), so i think i have to use eulers forumla $e^{i \theta} = cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$ ? @joanpemo

Comment: @combostudent I think so...and yes: there are no real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Joanpemo so I got $\lambda = 2 +/- 2i$. So... I just do $cos(2+2i)+isin(2+2i)$ ?

Comment: @combostudent No. what you get **is already** the eigenvalue! If you want, you can write it down in polar form, for example: $$2-2i=\sqrt8e^{-\pi i/4}=2\sqrt2\left(\cos\frac\pi4-i\sin\frac\pi4\right)$$